# putting matrix & arrrow and image in one line

Tags: horizontal-alignment

i am creating presentation in latex.

I want to demonstrate the conversion from matrix to sth. Therefore, i want to create something like that;

> Matrix => an Image

I know how to write matrix or image in latex but i could not put them in  a line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you mean a real matrix and an included graphic file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use `\raisebox` on the graphic, knowing the proper shift to be

`-.5\dimexpr\height-\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox`, regardless of the graphic size.

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow
\raisebox{-.5\dimexpr\height-\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}{%
  \includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image-A}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

To demonstrate the portability of the shift, here is the same code when the graphic height is 0.25in

[image]